# Use Memcached in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, memcached, cakephp-3.0

How can I access a memcached database in cakephp without using the CakePhp MemcachedEngine.php? 
When I try to create a **new Memcached()** Object, Cake doesn't recognize that I need the php class and gives me an error like:

***Class 'App\Controller\Memcached' not found***

I don't want to use CakePHP's implementation of MemcachedEngine, because we had some issues with it. Is there any Memcached.php File which I can include with e.g. require_once()...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try put at the top of your class: `use \Memcached;` or use `new \Memcached()`.